# Corrupt mercurial repository - cannot update

Tags: mercurial, corrupt

i think ive managed to corrupt one of mercurial repositories, is there anyway to recover the damage? the message i get when attempting to update the repo to my default branch is:

```
PS C:\wco\projects\ims\code> hg up -C default
abort: data/Trunk/application/models/priority_model.php.i@83dbdfb60981: no match found!
```

when i run hg verify, i get the following report:

```
PS C:\wco\projects\ims\code> hg verify
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
 data/.buildpath.i@0: missing revlog!
 0: empty or missing .buildpath
 .buildpath@0: daf15acb5273 in manifests not found
 data/.project.i@0: missing revlog!
 0: empty or missing .project
 .project@0: e8b25997d6d1 in manifests not found
 Rawlings IMS/index.html@3: empty or missing copy source revlog index.html:b8b2b36a6eea
 Rawlings IMS/index.php@3: empty or missing copy source revlog index.php:a5f76bf232e9
 Rawlings IMS/index_backup.php@3: empty or missing copy source revlog index_backup.php:a5f76bf232e9
 Rawlings IMS/index_this_hold.html@3: empty or missing copy source revlog index_this_hold.html:b8b2b36a6eea
 Rawlings IMS/testera.php@3: empty or missing copy source revlog testera.php:6e9e3666c1bc
 Trunk/application/models/priority_model.php@32: 83dbdfb60981 in manifests not found
 data/index.html.i@0: missing revlog!
 0: empty or missing index.html
 index.html@0: b8b2b36a6eea in manifests not found
 data/index.php.i@0: missing revlog!
 0: empty or missing index.php
 index.php@0: a5f76bf232e9 in manifests not found
 data/index_backup.php.i@0: missing revlog!
 0: empty or missing index_backup.php
 index_backup.php@0: a5f76bf232e9 in manifests not found
 data/index_this_hold.html.i@0: missing revlog!
 0: empty or missing index_this_hold.html
 index_this_hold.html@0: b8b2b36a6eea in manifests not found
 data/nbproject/project.properties.i@14: missing revlog!
 14: empty or missing nbproject/project.properties
 nbproject/project.properties@14: 1efa3074378b in manifests not found
 data/nbproject/project.xml.i@14: missing revlog!
 14: empty or missing nbproject/project.xml
 nbproject/project.xml@14: 52689bf2b35a in manifests not found
 data/rcrawley/.buildpath.i@9: missing revlog!
 9: empty or missing rcrawley/.buildpath
 rcrawley/.buildpath@9: 2c6411d4fcff in manifests not found
 data/rcrawley/.project.i@9: missing revlog!
 9: empty or missing rcrawley/.project
 rcrawley/.project@9: cb4b1495acab in manifests not found
 data/rcrawley/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif.i@9: missing revlog!
 9: empty or missing rcrawley/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif
 rcrawley/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif@9: 8ef26516c7da in manifests not found
 data/rcrawley/index.html.i@9: missing revlog!
 9: empty or missing rcrawley/index.html
 rcrawley/index.html@9: 545246299dee in manifests not found
 data/rcrawley/index.php.i@9: missing revlog!
 9: empty or missing rcrawley/index.php
 rcrawley/index.php@9: 66eac798ed6d in manifests not found
 data/rcrawley/index_backup.php.i@9: missing revlog!
 9: empty or missing rcrawley/index_backup.php
 rcrawley/index_backup.php@9: 93971228fbf5 in manifests not found
 data/rcrawley/system/index.html.i@9: missing revlog!
 9: empty or missing rcrawley/system/index.html
 rcrawley/system/index.html@9: 17360d3b566e in manifests not found
 data/rcrawley/testera.php.i@9: missing revlog!
 9: empty or missing rcrawley/testera.php
 rcrawley/testera.php@9: 7d9bd5196740 in manifests not found
 data/testera.php.i@0: missing revlog!
 0: empty or missing testera.php
 testera.php@0: 6e9e3666c1bc in manifests not found
1646 files, 59 changesets, 1897 total revisions
57 integrity errors encountered!
(first damaged changeset appears to be 0)
```

since the first damaged changeset is 0, this would appear to be pretty terminal. Is there anyway around this?

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @richzilla: can't help here but I've got a local "push only" repository to which I only ever push when my main repository passed an *"hg verify"*.  That way should the sh*t hit the fan there's always one repo on my machine in a known good state.  Don't know if this makes any sense but I do it anyway :)

Comment: Please open a bugreport (so many missing revlog means there isn't much we can do, but we can try to find out how it happened).

Comment: Btw your best bet is an hg->hg convert with a filemap to exclude the missing files (and I bet you removed files based on a pattern, which removed stuff inside .hg).

The other question is: do you have a backup, or a working repository elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repo appears fried - and post this as a bug report to the Mercurial bug tracker & talk to `mpm` on the mercurial irc chatroom, he's very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

hg.ignoreerrors also let missing revlog errors to be ignored when reading the source, which may be useful to fix a repository with a damaged store. Set this option to True and convert from Mercurial to Mercurial.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension

Read [this section](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryCorruption#Recovery_using_convert_extension) (trying hg convert).